# what does the global:: stand for in C#

Tags: c#, .net

What does the global:: stand for in C#? for example what is the difference between

```
private global::System.Int32 myInt;
```

and

```
private int myInt;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's the "global" namespace - it forces the compiler to look for a name without taking other using directives into consideration. For example, suppose you had:

```
public class Bar{}

namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar {}

    public class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Bar bar1 = null; // Refers to Foo.Bar
            global::Bar bar2 = null; // Refers to the "top level" Bar
        }
    }
}
```

Basically it's a way of avoiding naming collisions - you're most likely to see it in tool-generated code, where the tool doesn't necessarily know all the other types in the system. It's rarer to need it in manually-written code.

See ["How to: Use the global namespace alias"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx) on MSDN for more details, along with the [`::` namespace qualifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad.aspx).

Comment: That's right, It is generated by Microsoft entity framework, when trying to generate code out from a .edmx file. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

It is the global namespace alias.

If you declare a type called `System.Int32` in your codebase, you can distinguish the built in .NET one using this alias.

```
// your code
namespace System
{
  public class Int32
  {
  }
}

// You could reference the BCL System.Int32 like this:
global::System.Int32 bclInt;
System.Int32 myInt;
```

See [How to: Use the Global Namespace Alias (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Your `Int32` is `global::System.Int32`: your `System` namespace isn't nested. Also, namespaces don't have visibility.

Comment: @hvd: Of course namespaces have *visibility*; they must have *visibility* because they can be *hidden*, and a *hidden* namespace is by definition not *visible*. I think perhaps you meant to say that namespaces do not have *accessibility*, though that is an odd way to characterize namespace accessibility; a better way to think of it is that *all namespaces have public accessibility*.

Comment: @EricLippert I'll admit I've never heard of hidden namespaces. Having looked it up: are you referring to namespaces in an external assembly containing only internal classes? If so, Visual Studio and the C# compiler disagree on whether they're visible: `using System.Data.Entity.Internal;` is underlined as an error, but accepted by the compiler. I don't know what the spec says.

Comment: @EricLippert Regardless, I agree that visibility was not the right word, I could have better worded is as "Accessibility modifiers aren't allowed on namespaces; namespaces don't allow for different accessibility levels in the way that classes and class members do."

Comment: @hdv: No, I am not referring to that. Consider `namespace N { class C { class N { class C {} class D { N.C c } } } }`. In the declaration of field `c` the namespace `N` is hidden by the class `N`. Any namespace may be hidden. By definition a namespace which is not *hidden* and is *in scope* is *visible*. I refer you to the C# 4 language specification, section 3.7.1.

Comment: @EricLippert Ah, okay, no argument there. In that case, again, my terminology was unprecise. It's still possible to refer to `global::N.C`, so in that sense it is not hidden, but that sense is not how the language specification uses the word. Thanks, I'll try to work on using terms such as these in the same way as the spec.

Comment: @hvd: I am perhaps over-precise but that's kinda my job. :-)  I note that it is somewhat unfortunate that the CLR team uses "visible" to mean "accessible", which I consider to be an imprecise choice of words. The peak of a mountain that you cannot climb is not *invisible*, it is *inaccessible*.

Answer (score 2):

It is used to refer to the global namespace. This is useful if you're writing code in a namespace that already exists elsewhere.

See this for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx