# Roslyn CSharpExtractMethodService generate method parameters with global:: prefix, why not simple int[]?

Tags: c#, methods, extract, global, roslyn

When I extract method from this code, final result have `global::System.Int32[]` list as parameter in `NewMethod`:

```cs
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new int[] {3, 2, 1 };

        foreach(var i in list) Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Final result:

```cs
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new int[] { 3, 2, 1 };
        NewMethod(list);
    }

    private static void NewMethod(**global::System.Int32[] list**)
    {
        foreach (var i in list) Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

I use this this Roslyn class to extract method:

```cs
var options = new ExtractMethodGenerationOptions()
    {CodeGenerationOptions = CodeGenerationOptions.GetDefault(document.Project.Services),
    ExtractOptions = new() { DontPutOutOrRefOnStruct = true}}

var service = new CSharpExtractMethodService() as IExtractMethodService;
var extract = await service.ExtractMethodAsync(document, span, false,options, CancellationToken.None);
var result = extract.DocumentWithoutFinalFormatting;
```

Why I have `global::`, when I extract method with Visual Studio, the `NewMethod` have simple `int[]` list as method parameter?

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443357/what-does-the-global-stand-for-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thank you Frenchy, but how I can get only simple types (int[]), and not global::Int32[]? :)

Comment: try to add a namespace to your class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code, I replace global:: with simple types:

```
public class MySimplifier
    {
        public static async Task<Document> SimplifyTypes(Document document)
        {
            var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            var editor = await DocumentEditor.CreateAsync(document).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var nodesToReplace = root.DescendantNodesAndSelf()
            .OfType<TypeSyntax>()
            .Where(n => n.ToString().StartsWith("global::"))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var node in nodesToReplace)
        {
            var typeName = node.ToString().Substring("global::".Length);
            var simpleType = GetSimpleType(typeName);
            if (simpleType != null)
            {
                var newType = SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(simpleType);
                editor.ReplaceNode(node, newType);
            }
        }

        return editor.GetChangedDocument();
    }

    private static string GetSimpleType(string typeName)
    {
        switch (typeName)
        {
            case "System.Boolean":
                return "bool";
            case "System.Byte":
                return "byte";
            case "System.Char":
                return "char";
            case "System.Decimal":
                return "decimal";
            case "System.Double":
                return "double";
            case "System.Int16":
                return "short";
            case "System.Int32":
                return "int";
            case "System.Int64":
                return "long";
            case "System.SByte":
                return "sbyte";
            case "System.Single":
                return "float";
            case "System.String":
                return "string";
            case "System.UInt16":
                return "ushort";
            case "System.UInt32":
                return "uint";
            case "System.UInt64":
                return "ulong";
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Take the final document and then run it through our [Simplifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.simplification.simplifier?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.3.0) API. Generally, when we do refactorings, we internally expand names to fully qualified things (global:: and all) and the as final pass clean everything back up. This allows us to potentially move that code around to other files or places where qualification may have to be different.

Comment: I try with this Simplifier: 

           var doc = extract.DocumentWithoutFinalFormatting;
            var simple = await Simplifier.ReduceAsync(doc!);

But I get same result, parameters with global::System.Int32.

Maybe I should define some OptionSet in ReduceAsync call?